# REST API - appropriate method and route to have child change what its parent resource is

Tags: rest, routes, http-method

Let's say I have 2 models, `Location` and `Item`, that correspond to 2 tables in a database, represented in c# below. Is something like a `PATCH` request to `/items/{itemId}` appropriate to change the location id of an item to refer to a different location resource?  This is the first time I've been in a situation where I want to change the parent of a resource so I am unsure of the appropriate method and route.  I'm working with DTO (data transfer objects) so ideally what I want to do is acceptable so I can have just one DTO patch class for updates to the Item model.

```
public class Location {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ushort RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Item {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AssetNumber { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public long LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your url is `/items/{itemId}` and not something like `/location/{locationId}/items/{itemId}`, I don't think there's any thing special about changing the `locationId` versus any other property from a HTTP/Rest perspective.

And `PATCH` is a good way to make a partial change to a resource.

Comment: I think I will be implementing such an end point, but it wouldn't be used too often.  Would the problem then be that a consumer of the api might store identifiers(e.g. 5 and 3 for `/location/5/items/3`), but an items location id changing would make that invalid?  If so, what do you do then?